# Porto theme assistance

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, porto-theme

Sorry for such a basic query but the person who set up Porto has left and I find it impossible to find specific pages in the backend.

We had Ultimo when I last had to make any changes and that was easy - just search for a page but it doesn't work with porto which seems to have its own menu.

Basically, I need to put a message on our home page to warn customers of postal delays/last order dates for Christmas and I need to amend information on our returns page.

I can't find either of them. Under "Web" on the menu I can see the title for CMS home page but there is no link to edit it there so assume I am looking in totally the wrong space.

Apologies again for such a basic query - any help really appreciated!
With thanks
Susan

Answer (score 0):

You will find the option to edit the home page and other CMS pages such as a returns page in Magento Admin>Content>Pages